# Cutomize Delete button react-admin

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

Is there any way to customise `DeleteButton` button in `react-admin` to add a confirmation message like 'Do you want to delete item?'. Currently on clicking on `DeleteButton` it directly deletes the item without asking for a confirmation. I tried adding `title` attribute to delete button but it does not get fired.
Here is my code

```
//This worked with admin-on-rest, but not working with react-admin
const CategoryDeleteTitle = translate(({ record, translate }) => <span>
        {translate('Delete')}&nbsp;
        {record && `${record.code} ${record.name}`}
    </span>);

const EditActions = ({ basePath, data, resource }) => (
    <CardActions>
        <ShowButton basePath={basePath} record={data} />
        <ListButton basePath={basePath} />
        <DeleteButton title={<CategoryTitle />} basePath={basePath} record={data} resource={resource} />

    </CardActions>
);

export const CategoryEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit actions={<EditActions />} title={<CategoryTitle />} {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <DisabledInput source="id" />
            <TextInput source="name" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

Comment: How do I add a alert?

Comment: give me some time. i'll post the answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I have edited the question to show what I have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We now handle deletions in an optimistic way, providing an undo mechanism instead of a confirmation dialog.

If this doesn't suit you, you can follow the [UPGRADE GUIDE](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/UPGRADE.md#removed-the-delete-view-in-resource) which leads to this page of the documentation: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#actions

Note that you'll have to create and handle your confirmation dialog using something like `react-modals` and dispatch the `DELETE` action yourself.

Comment: Thanks Gildas I have customised `DeleteButton` to show the confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/adylevy/759900e7c50f9ccebe9f037bc5e32506) with custom actions like:

```
const UserEditActions = ({ basePath, data, resource }) => (
    <CardActions>
        <ListButton basePath={basePath} />
        <DeleteButtonWithConfirmation basePath={basePath} record={data} resource={resource} undoable={false} />
        <RefreshButton />
      </CardActions>
    );

export const UserEdit = ({ ...props }) => (
  <Edit {...props} actions={<UserEditActions />} >
    <CreateEditForm title={<EntityTitle label="User" />} />
  </Edit>
);
```

Comment: The gist does not mention licensing information. Can you add MIT information on it?

Comment: @Tzahi - Updated.

Answer (score 3):

In react-admin v3, there is now a DeleteWithConfirmButton :-)

Comment: I cannot see any reference to this component in v3.7.0 : https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Reference.html Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: Didn't find anything regarding this in the documentation

Comment: Yeah, but there is it https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/eb3c1acbf4ecc81793b8e790e11a6f84f9bdbc1b/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/DeleteWithConfirmButton.tsx

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation "https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html" create:

```
const CustomToolbar = props => (
    <Toolbar {...props} classes={useStyles()}>
        <SaveButton />
        <DeleteButton undoable={false} />
    </Toolbar>
);
```

import from react-admin button you need like this:

```
import {
    Toolbar,
    SaveButton,
    DeleteWithConfirmButton
} from 'react-admin';
```

see all available names here https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button, and change DeleteButton on ImportedButton like this:

```
 export const CustomToolbar = props => (
    <Toolbar {...props} classes={useStyles()}>
        <SaveButton/>
        <DeleteWithConfirmButton/>
    </Toolbar>
);
```

And change in the code, where you need `<SimpleForm toolbar={<CustomToolbar />}>`.